# subprocess.poll() not working

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.4

I cannot get subprocess.poll() to work in any situation. It keeps complaining:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./JobScheduler.py", line 41, in ?
    while job1.alive():
  File "./JobScheduler.py", line 26, in alive
    if self.process.poll() is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python (using version 2.4)
import sys, subprocess, threading, random, time, logging

class Command(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd):
        super(Command, self).__init__()
        self.cmd        = cmd
        self.process    = None
        self.jobid      = None
        self.returncode = None

    def run(self):
        print "%s: starting job..." % self.getName()
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0, shell=True)
        out, err = self.process.communicate()
        self.returncode = self.process.returncode
        print "Process complete:"
        print "  returncode=" + str(self.returncode)
        print "  output=" + out

    def alive(self):
        if self.process.poll() is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getJobID(self):
        return self.jobid

job1 = Command(cmd)
job1.start()
job2 = Command(cmd)
job2.start()
print "MAIN: Jobs started."

while job1.alive():
    print "job still running."
    time.sleep(10)

sys.exit(0)
```

I've tried using poll() in every possible way and simply cannot get it to work. The point where the while() loop is executed the processes are still running.

Sample output:

```
# ./JobScheduler.py 
Thread-1: starting job...
Thread-2: starting job...
MAIN: Jobs started.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./JobScheduler.py", line 41, in ?
    while job1.alive():
  File "./JobScheduler.py", line 26, in alive
    if self.process.poll() is None:
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is why I was messing with adding a `self._lock` in my answer to your other question on this topic. :)

Comment: Good old fashioned race condition you've got there.

Comment: Why not `.wait()` the process in the run method and `.join()` the "runner" thread in the main thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `self.process.poll()` before `self.process` has been assigned a value. When you start the thread, it starts by calling your `run()` method, but your main code continues to run. You end up calling `job1.alive()` before `job1.run()` has done any useful work yet.

Comment: So what is the proper approach to doing this? If I hardcode in a sleep(10) before the while loop, it works. But hardcoding a sleep statement doesn't seem robust to me. 10 seconds might be enough in this test case, but a loaded system it might not be.

Comment: You could initialise `self.process` in the `__init__` method, then call `communicate()` in the `run` method. That way it will never be `None`.

Comment: Ahh works line a charm calling Popen in init(). *bonks self on head* I must have tried every possible permutation of stuff except that. Thx!